# Modify the app a model belongs to in the Django admin index

Tags: django, django-admin, satchmo

I am making a Satchmo site and I want to add models that don't currently exist. These new models all appear under the app that they are defined in. This is fine for programmers, but I want the client might not understand why the the menu lists "Store Map" under "Local Site" and not under "Shop". Is there any way to modify which app a model appears under in the admin index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the [`app_label` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#app-label) in the model's meta:

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'my_app'
```

Comment: Actually, south apparently doesn't care fro that. I would have to run a schemamigration on the third party code which is what I'm trying to avoid.